# Copy data from a large table on a test server to a table on production server in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I want to copy data from a table in our test server to a table in our production server. The table has 50 million rows in it. One of the ways I was planning on doing it was to have two tasks:

1. Use the data flow task to export the data from the source table to a CSV file.
2. Use the Bulk Insert flow task to read from the CSV file and insert it into the destination table.

Is there a better way to do this in SSIS? Thanks!

Comment: Are the servers housing these databases on the same network? You could just run a Data import task (though it would take an extended amount of time to complete)

Comment: There are many options but we need to know objectives and constraints. Any question asking "better" or "best" does not explain these constraints and objectives. For example, does it need to be SSIS? It might be quicker using BCP native format, This is a simple command line, does not requiring field mapping. This supports round trip of data types, and doesn't have the delimiting issues that text files have. Another way is backup / restore to a local database and do a cross database insert/select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches to transfer data between two servers. SSIS is not always the preferred one. Noting that 50 million rows are not always considered a large data set; It depends on the server resources, columns data types, and other factors.

The simplest way to import/ export data is to use the [SSMS Import/Export wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15). Another approach is to use BCP as @Nick.McDermaid mentioned in the comments.

If you have limited physical resources, and you need to do this using SSIS, you can try loading data in batches as explained in the following article:

- [SQL OFFSET FETCH Feature: Loading Large Volumes of Data Using Limited Resources with SSIS](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-offset-fetch-feature-loading-large-volumes-of-data-using-limited-resources-with-ssis/)